# Remove the dust on the keyboard

Tags: discussion, design

A while ago, when one used `<kbd>Enter</kbd>` the output was clean and beautiful: [image]. Since one UI update (can't tell which) the kbd now have an ugly background-color : <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I find it unpleasant and not very consistent since this is the same color used in the `Code Sample` section which doesn't have the same meaning (unless you have keys that write code with one press).

May we rollback to previous CSS?

Comment: Just means we repented of using chiclet keys and went back to mechanical switches with proper beige key-caps.

Comment: Maybe it's time for black keyboard keys? That might look pretty sharp.

Comment: For next year's April Fool's, SO should "revert" to "real" chiclet keys (image of a baby chick with letters on it). ;-)

Comment: From the title, I thought this was a burnination request. I feel cheated. I'm outta here. Good day to you, sir.

Comment: Revert to original --> meta design bug report about keyboard markdown having misaligned baseline...

Comment: I think they might have tried to nail that aluminum look, but failed.

Comment: I actually like the new look.

Comment: lol, Shog9. +1 for you @tniles09. That seems like a logical step since that's what almost all keyboards are now.

Comment: This is also not a bug please remove the bug tag.  A bug is when something isn't broken, not whether you like / dislike a shade of gray.

Comment: @JonH `bug tag` => *This tag indicates a reproducible problem on the site that you believe is due to a mistake*, since I believe that it's due to a mistake, I tagged it as a bug

Comment: @ThomasAyoub: It's obviously not a "mistake", but an intentional design choice, even if you disagree with that choice.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett [you are still on time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyboard)

Comment: With the shape like that you thought it was code - come on people this is getting ridiculous.

Comment: I also like the old one, just because to me the new one *does* look like somebody accidentally used the wrong color for the text background - if you make it look gray (which is fine, I have no personal preference as to actual color), it should be gray all the way out to the edge of the "button," not just gray on the text part.

Comment: THIS IS A BUG!!!!!!!!!!!!!! When people mess with the `<kbd>` discussion time is OVER!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I can't look at my collection of [castles and keyboards](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-intrusive) until this is fixed!

Comment: @brandaemon OH MY. **How** have I been on SO, MSO, MSE for so long and not seen that *awesomeness*?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett I thought you were going to suggest [this kind of chiclet](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a3/Chiclets-Candies.jpg) keys

Comment: I first noticed this around the time when the new green theme was being rolled out.

Comment: @ThomasAyoub It doesn't matter--not to me, at least--that the background colour of the keys is similar to that of code snippets. This issue feels like bikeshedding. Does it really bother you so much that it makes posting this worthwhile? Everyone here, including myself, could have used this time to do something useful and worthwhile. :) :D

Comment: @Mohamad nobody forced you to waste a minute of your time to read this question and the same amount of time to write this comment :) It bothered me enough to take 5 minutes of my free time to post here, and, given the amount of votes, seems not to be the only one bothered

Comment: @ThomasAyoub can't argue with statistics ;)

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have stolen the stylesheet on numberous occassions. I will dig it up.

Comment: The Enter key version you are saying is ugly looks beautiful in my CSS which seems to destroy the background and leave only the border and text... whereas the original stands out rather sorely against my 'white text on black background' thing I have going on (it has a white background around the key). I must ask we keep the current Enter key for great justice. Or perhaps just remove the forced background around the old key.

Comment: Damn I thought you would talk about how to literally remove the dust (junk) on the keyboard and hoped to find the answer!

The topic of this question was successful.

Comment: My keyboard is black with no keycaps at all.

Answer (score 52):

Just for reference, the original CSS looked probably like this:

```css
kbd, span.kbrd {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 0 2px #ffffff inset;
    color: #333333;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    margin: 0 0.1em;
    padding: 0.1em 0.6em;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

I know it because I shamelessly ripped it and used in some documentation.

Comment: And you gave credit where credit was due right ? :)

Comment: Does `/* stackoverflow keyboard style*/` count?

Comment: Looks good to me...

Comment: I don't think it had that background color, my memory (and memory is flawed, as we know) is that it was even lighter than that, perhaps even white like the image in the question.

Comment: @JonH "This code was produced with 99% recycled Stackoverflow content."

Comment: Thanks for that, @Tomáš - now added to my Stylish for SE...